# Need to type only email id instead of text in jquery token input

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

[image]

I want, only the email should be accepted in the token input, not an ordinary text..

Comment: put a email validation before submitting the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery validation for checking email or not.

Eg:

```
function IsEmail(email) {
 var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
return regex.test(email);
}
```

pass email value to `email` parameter to IsEmail function.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Vinod's answer, and relate it to the jquery-tokeninput plugin you specified, I don't believe there is a method specifically built to validate free-text input prior to it being added.

I'd recommend making use of the `onAdd` callback, running the item (passed as parameter) through Vinod's isEmail function there, and then removing the new item if it fails the regex test.

Untested Example Code: (You may need to alter the remove method, I'm not sure if it takes an actual object, or a JSON string.)

```
$("#my-text-input").tokenInput("/url/to/your/script/",{
   onAdd: function(item){
       if(!isEmail(item.value)) $("#my-text-input").tokenInput("remove", item);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out this and it works fine for me..

```
For your kind reference..

resultsFormatter: function(item){    
var email_regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
console.log("item.email"+item.email);
if(item.email != null){
console.log("Email lalal:: "+item.email);
return "<li>" + item.name +" &lt;"+item.email+"&gt;"+"</li>";   
}
if(item.name.match(email_regex)){
return "<li>" +" Private Student "+ item.name+ "</li>";
}else{
return "<li style='display:none;'>" +" "+"</li>";   
}                   
}
}
```